# Eclipse hover documentation displaying raw HTML

Tags: eclipse, code-assist

I am running Eclipse Indigo x64 on RedHat 6, and anytime the hover documentation pops up, the raw HTML is being displayed as plain text.  This is the case with my PHP projects, where under the preferences, PHP > Code Style > Formatter (PDT Tools), I have created my own Active profile. I noticed that with the Java Formatter profile, "Eclipe [built-in]", under the comments tab, there is an option box "Format HTML tags". The PHP Formatter profile does not have a comments tab, so I believe this could be what the issue is.

Is there a way to specify this in the profile?

If anyone has resolved this issue, please let me know.

Comment: did you find a fix for this problem? Have been searching a little but can't find any solution. I remember I had this same issue sometime ago and the solution was to install a little utility program in ubuntu. But I can't remember the name of that program. But I know this problem has little to with eclipse itself.

Comment: i haven't found a fix for this. i ended up switching to PHPStorm and haven't looked back.

Comment: I think i may have found one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution could be simply a one line addition to `eclipse.ini` . Here is what I did to solve it
Open `eclipse.ini` (inside the eclipse folder) in a text editor and add

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit
```

to it if not already there with a different value.

Make sure you have at least `libwebkitgtk-1.0.0` or `libwebkitgtk-3.0.0` or both installed on your system. ( you can do `sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0.0` on Ubuntu).

My guess is the content assist view relies on the internal web browser to parse its HTML content. So if eclipse (and its settings) are not providing one then the raw HTML is displayed. This solution also fixed issues i had with other plugins that relied on internal web browsers like the Eclipse Colorer theme plugin

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Can you please help me to install  libwebkitgtk-3.0.0 on ubuntu 20.04 LTS. When using sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-3.0.0 it is giving error like- source E: Package 'libwebkitgtk-3.0-0' has no installation candidate.